# Workbox background sync cant match Regex

Tags: progressive-web-apps, service-worker, workbox, workbox-webpack-plugin

When using workbox background sync plugin i have to create a route to catch the requests. But I want to catch all urls that contains /api/

From [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-background-sync) This is the default regex **//api/.*/*.json/**

```
registerRoute(
  /\/api\/.*\/*.json/,
  new NetworkOnly({
    plugins: [bgSyncPlugin]
  }),
  'POST'
);
```

The regex will match https://example.com **/api/test.json**

Im trying to do this to match all url that has /api/ in url
for example:

https://example.com/api/user/add/ and
https://somethingelse.com/api/todo/add/

But for some reason when im doing this:

```
registerRoute(
  new RegExp(/.*\/api\/.*/),
  new NetworkOnly({
    plugins: [bgSyncPlugin]
  }),
  'POST'
);
```

the background sync plugin does not catch the post request. I dont understand why it would not work, the regex does match when testing it in [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/ONJsZN/1/)

Why is workbox background sync plugin not working with `new RegExp('.*\/api\/.*/')` on `https://example.com/api/users/`

Also I have confirmed that this is the issue. When matching my domain url specifically it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's some background about this in the [Workbox documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/route-requests#matching_a_route_with_a_regular_expression):

> Just like with string matching, requests for different origins are
> treated differently. Instead of matching against any part of the URL,
> the regular expression must match from the beginning of the URL in
> order to trigger a route when there's a cross-origin request.
>
> For example, the previous regular expression `new RegExp('/blog/\\d{4}/\\d{2}/.+')` would not match a request for
> `https://some-other-origin.com/blog/<year>/<month>/<post title slug>`.
> If we wanted a route that would match that general path pattern made
> against both same- and cross-origin requests, using a regular
> expression with a wildcard (`.+`) at the start is one approach:

Because this could end up being awkward, we've started encouraging folks to use [callback functions](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/route-requests#handling_a_route_with_a_custom_callback) as the criteria instead:

```js
registerRoute(
  ({url}) => url.pathname.includes('/api/'),
  new NetworkOnly({
    plugins: [bgSyncPlugin]
  }),
  'POST'
);
```

Comment: Totally did not see that in the documentation, how the regex need to be matched is the issue then. Anyway, callback function looks much nicer than the regex. Thanks!